# Selmer Group of number fields and Ideal lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices, quadratic-forms

Let $K$ be a totally real number field of degree $n$ and dicriminant $d$, in   [this article of F.Lemmermeyer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5674.pdf)  the selmer group of $K$ is defined as

$$\text{Sel}(K):=\{\alpha \in K^{\times}: (\alpha)=\mathfrak{a}^2   \}/K^{\times\,2}.$$
We also have the subgroup of totally positive elements, given by

$$\text{Sel}^{+}(K):=\{\alpha \in K^{\times}: (\alpha)=\mathfrak{a}^2   ,\alpha \gg 0\}/K^{\times\,2}.$$

Now let $\mathcal{C}(d)$ the set of isometry classes of positive definite integral lattices of rank $n$ and discrimant $d$. Then we have a natural function

$$\psi:\text{Sel}^{+}(K) \to \mathcal{C}(d)$$

mapping $\alpha K^{\times\,2}$ to the class of $(\mathfrak{a},b_{\alpha})$ where $(\alpha)=\mathfrak{a}^2$ and  $b_{\alpha}(x,y)=\text{tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\frac{x\cdot y}{\alpha})$ for all $x, y \in \mathfrak{a}$. Note that $(\mathfrak{a},b_{\alpha})$ is an integral ideal lattice in the sense defined by Eva Bayer-Fluckiger [here](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=Up-XxkiTtdsC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=Ideal%20Lattices,%20in%20A%20Panorama%20of%20Number%20Theory&source=bl&ots=yROhnI1qqK&sig=OZzN1IEkVugoWs8eGeqQb16y4-c&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSp6nGuMvWAhUHMyYKHa9qArQQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=Ideal%20Lattices%2C%20in%20A%20Panorama%20of%20Number%20Theory&f=false).

**My question is:**

Suppose $\text{Aut}(K)$ is trival, then is $\psi$ injective?.

I put  $\text{Aut}(K)=\{1\}$ because if $1 \neq \sigma \in \text{Aut}(K) $, then 
$\psi \left( \alpha K^{\times\,2} \right) = \psi \left( \sigma(\alpha)K^{\times\,2} \right) $ but not necessarily $\alpha / \sigma(\alpha) \in K^{\times\,2}$. For example, in the cyclic cubic field $K$ defined by $x^3-x^2-234x+729$, the three roots of $x^3-41 x^2+326x-1$ give diferent elements of the Selmer group with the same image by $\psi$.

I've verifed this in MAGMA for **all** the fields in NumberFieldDatabase(m) for $2<m<10$. But I can't find any idea to get a proof.